# jqueryui button state not changing on prop call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using a simple prop call to change the state of a `jqueryui` "toggle" button (aka `checkbox`) using this:
`$("#completed_button").prop("checked", true);`

Functionally the checkbox is changing state and the script is operating properly. Unfortunately it is not changing the visual state of the button. Any idea why its not and what I can do to make it so?

Example: Below the middle is what it looks like when you use the mouse to toggle, right is what happens when i use the above call. Notice how the text is correct, but the visual highlight is not.

[image]

Comment: A little more code would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the jQuery-UI elements for the button are listening for change events from the toggle button but the change event doesn't fire when you say `.prop('checked', true)`. This behavior goes all the way back to the [DOM Level 2 Event Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

Calling `.prop('checked', true)` (or even `.attr('checked', 'checked')`) doesn't alter the focus so no change event occurs.

The solution is to trigger the change event yourself:

```
$("#completed_button").prop("checked", true).change();
```

That should let the jQuery-UI wrapper know that the checkbox has changed state and then the jQuery-UI visual will also change.

Here's a quick demo that illustrates what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8et3G/

Comment: Amazing reply! Thank you.
I love that it was a simple fix and that you gave back-story as to why it was happening. No wonder you have 61.7k rep.