# Event when checkbox is checked by removeAttr('checked')

Tags: jquery

I have a function that unchecks a checkbox by doing this:

```
$('[name = destination]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Now I want an event to fire on the checkbox, the same as if I had checked it manually. Is there an event for this?

I've tried change and click. Both work when I check/uncheck the box manually, but not when it's done like this.

Comment: "I've tried change and click." Where's the code you tried for that part?

Comment: $('[name = destination]').live('change', function() {

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the attribute why don't you set the property to false

```
$('[name = destination]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Try

```
$('[name = destination]').prop('checked', false);
```

---

Then write up the event which handles this functionality you are looking for

```
$('[name = destination]').on('click' , function(){
  var $chk = $('[name="description"]');
  if($chk.is(':checked')){
       console.log('Checkbox is checked !!');
  }
  else{
       console.log('Checkbox is now UNCHECKED !!');
  }
});

$('[name = destination]').prop('checked', false).trigger('click');
```

You can also trigger the event manually by using `.trigger()` method

```
  $('[name = destination]').trigger('click');
```

**Be careful when you trigger the event**

The current property state might not be reflected in this case if you are using **this** to check the status

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ntu7M/)**

Comment: You'd still need to trigger an event, wouldn't you?

Comment: Doesn't work. The click and change events still aren't fired with .prop('checked', false);

Comment: Try this `$('[name = destination]').prop('checked', false).trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to manually trigger a `change` or `click` event when you change the `checked` attribute (and you should probably do this via `prop` instead of `changeAttribute`, as another poster mentioned)

This just means instead of just

```
$('[name = destination]').removeAttr('checked');
```

do

```
$('[name = destination]').removeAttr('checked');
$('[name = destination]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to remember to trigger this event in every function where the box is checked or unchecked. Perhaps there is no such way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796680/jqueryui-button-state-not-changing-on-prop-call would seem to confirm.

Comment: Ah well. I'll use this trigger method. Thanks. (I can accept in 6 minutes)

Comment: Ah no. It didn't work. Triggering click or change actually causes the box to BE clicked/changed. But that's what I just did with .removeAttr('checked'); It actually undoes what I just did. I guess I'll just have to define and explicitly call a function that does what I want it to do. Or verify the checked status of the box and then decide if I want to trigger a click or not.

Comment: btw, though, remember that you could (and if this is everywhere, probably should) make a function to do the check-- this way you won't have to remember to check.

Answer (score 0):

fire event by
$('[name = destination]').click();

It will act as you clicked on checkbox manually